# How do I print each individual array item as a template variable in Django?

Tags: python, django

I got a field in a Django modal as the following:

```
tags = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=50)
```

and within that field I have the value of:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

I'm currently trying to have it print out "One", "Two", and "Three" separately in a Django template using a for statement such as follows:

```
{% for tag in posts %} 
    {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it seems to be printing each individual charter from the array instead of the word itself. I know I'm over looking something here. Can someone by any chance help me or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope in your tags field you have exactly like.

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

You need to parse this string and pass it to the template. You should be able to access it as above. You can add a model method that does this for you. Ex:

```
class FooModel(models.Model):
    tags = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=50)

    def tags_list(self):
        try:
            return eval(self.tags)
        except:
            return None
```

Then in your template you can just do.

```
{% for tag in foo.tags_list %} 
    {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This works! Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know I had to parse the string and pass it back. Thank you.